# Inspiring Statuary = Improvise for Planeswalkers?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The card [Inspiring Statuary](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bInspiring%20Statuary%5d) states:

> Nonartifact spells you cast have improvise. *(Your artifacts
>   can help cast those spells. Each artifact you tap after you're done
>   activating mana abilities pays for {1}.)*

Are Planeswalkers considered Nonartifact spells, and therefore gain the keyword Improvise?

Comment: Even Karn Liberated is not an artifact.

Comment: @NeilMeyer I checked on him specifically before making my post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. A spell is anything that you cast to put on the stack. Basically every card except lands have the potential to be spells by casting them. As a planeswalker isn't an artifact (one could be, but none currently are), it is a nonartifact spell.

> 111.1. A spell is a card on the stack. As the first step of being cast (see rule 601, “Casting Spells”), the card becomes a spell and is moved to the top of the stack from the zone it was in, which is usually its owner’s hand. (See rule 405, “Stack.”) A spell remains on the stack as a spell until it resolves (see rule 608, “Resolving Spells and Abilities”), is countered (see rule 701.5), or otherwise leaves the stack.

Answer (score 5):

Planeswalkers are nonartifact spells. They do not have artifact on the type line, therefore, they are nonartifacts.